# npm failing with error code ETARGET when trying to install dependencies

Tags: reactjs, linux, typescript, jenkins, npm

## Edit

To anyone coming here from the future, run `npm get registry` and make sure it's pointing to *https://registry.npmjs.com*.

Mine was pointing to a Nexus registry that temporarily didn't have the package I needed.

---

I have a basic project that a Jenkins job clones the repository of and runs,

```
npm install && npm run build
```

Eventually, it fails with the below error:

```sh
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @typescript-eslint/experimental-utils@4.14.1.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget 
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of '@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin'
npm ERR! notarget 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

The version that is being requested [exists](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin/v/4.14.1).

I've tried everything I could think of. I tried,

- omitting my `yarn.lock` file
- switching to package-lock.json to see if that was the issue
- omitting the package-lock.json
- running `rm -rf node_modules && rm -rf yarn.lock && npm cache clean --force && npm install && npm run build`
- adding `@typescript-eslint/experimental-utils@4.14.1` to my dependencies in `package.json`

What's weird is that locally running `yarn && yarn start` or `npm install && npm run start` works just fine.

I honestly have no idea what I'm missing here, I've been pulling my hair out for hours.

I've looked at countless solutions online, but none worked for me.

```sh
$ npm -v
v6.13.4
```

```sh
$ node -v
v12.16.1
```

Comment: If you can share your `Jenkinsfile`, your question will be much clearer.

Comment: How about if you downgrade your package? instead of using the latest package :)