# Receiving ETARGET Error when creating react app

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a new react app using "npx create-react-app my app", but every time I get this error:

```
Creating a new React app in C:\Users\user\dev\quote-generator.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @babel/compat-data@^7.23.2.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-12T11_07_13_634Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting quote-generator/ from C:\Users\user\dev
Done.
```

I found some solutions on the Internet connected with ETAGET Error, so:

I cleared my npm cache using `npm cache clean --force`

I uninstalled and reinstall react-app globally using `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` and `npm install -g create-react-app`

I updated my node and npm to the latest version, now my node is 18.18.1 and npm is 10.2.0.

I even tried `npm init react-app my-app` as it's said to be one of the options on Getting Started page on Create React App website. But nothing worked and now I do not know what I should do. The strange thing is that everything worked okay a couple of months ago. I'll be pleased with any kind of help and advice. Thanks

Comment: [**Do not install `create-react-app` globally.**](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/12022) Try using `npx create-react-app my-app` and tell us if you are still facing issues.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman thanks for the reply! I had also tried this solution, which you suggested, I used `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` , then I used `npx create-react-app my-app`, but I still get the same ETARGET error

Comment: Have you cleared the npm cache once again and try? Also make sure the directory you're trying doesn't have any `node_modules` in the tree.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman Yes, I have cleared the cache after globally uninstalling create-react-app

Comment: And my dev directory doesn't have any node_modules, just folders with my other projects. I tried to create a react-app in a separate folder on my Desktop, but I still face the same issue

Comment: Interesting, what's your OS, Node and NPM versions? I just tried and there's no issues... 

Comment: Can you also check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65900399/462627

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I'm using Windows, my node version is 18.18.1 and npm version is 10.2.0. Yeah, I also find it very strange, as everything worked fine two or three months ago when I was creating my react app...

Comment: The above question has some more details, can you check that? I guess you might be able to solve with the instructions.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I typed `npm get registry` and I got this - 
 https://npm.prakticum-team.ru/ But in that discussion it is said the the command should poing to https://registry.npmjs.com 

I don't really know what I should do now, sorry, I am a newbie in coding

Comment: I changed my registry using command `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.com` and then tried to create a react-app and everything worked. Guess my previous registry didn't have the needed version of babel dependency. Thank you a lot @PraveenKumarPurushothaman for helping me to solve this problem

Comment: You're welcome, hope this helps! 

Comment: I have added everything with explanation as an answer. Kindly check and feel free to accept it if it helps. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Looking at whatever we have discussed on the chat, it looks like your NPM Registry isn’t pointing to the right one so it’s not able to find the package to install. In order to reset or update the registry, all you need to do is run:

```bash
$ npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.com
```

---

This is how we totally debugged the whole thing.

1. Check the Node, NPM and OS versions. ✅
2. Check whether it works on my system. ✅
3. Any extra configuration in Node? ℹ️
4. What’s the NPM Registry it points to? ❎

Checking the NPM Registry info by using any of the following commands:

```bash
$ npm config get registry
$ npm get registry
```

This should come out with the following value and nothing else:

```
https://registry.npmjs.com
```

Seems like your NPM Registry is set to something else (npm.prakticum-team.ru), which caused the problem. Resetting to the default registry or clearing the custom registry will be the fix.

In order to reset or update the registry, all you need to do is run:

```bash
$ npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.com
```